# Thread not running the inner loop in a kernel

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, nested-loops

I am doing an exercise, in which I have to use the Cuda kernels to optimize the execution time.

The kernel in function:

```c
__global__
void bodyForce(Body *p, float dt, int n) {
  int index = threadIdx.x + (blockDim.x * blockIdx.x);
  int stride = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;

  for (int i = index; i < n; i+= stride) {
    float Fx = 0.0f; float Fy = 0.0f; float Fz = 0.0f;

    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      float dx = p[j].x - p[i].x;
      float dy = p[j].y - p[i].y;
      float dz = p[j].z - p[i].z;
      float distSqr = dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz + SOFTENING;
      float invDist = rsqrtf(distSqr);
      float invDist3 = invDist * invDist * invDist; 
      
      Fx += dx * invDist3; Fy += dy * invDist3; Fz += dz * invDist3;
    }
    
    p[i].vx += dt*Fx; p[i].vy += dt*Fy; p[i].vz += dt*Fz;
  }
}
```

However, when assigning a thread to each iteration of the outer for, the threads do not run all the inner for, the inner for is always stuck at 0.

If each kernel thread is assigned a cycle of the outer for, shouldn't it also execute all the inner for until it reaches `n`? Or am I wrong?

Comment: `for (int i = index; i < n; i++ stride)` ???

Comment: @talonmies was a mistake while writing the question, my bad

Comment: This is not correct: `int stride = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;`  For example, a particular block in the grid will have a `blockIdx.x` of zero.  Consider what that means for the multiplication, and the loop.  Revisit what you were taught in that NVIDIA course about how to formulate a proper [grid stride loop](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cuda-pro-tip-write-flexible-kernels-grid-stride-loops/).

Comment: @RobertCrovella I have seen what you say and yes, thats the error. Thank you so much!